# Why can't I see any output when executing a windows batch file with VS code tasks

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying VS code tasks for the first time, I have created a `test.bat` file with

```
echo hello
```

and this `tasks.json`

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "test",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "cmd /c c:\\test\\test.bat"
        }
    ]
}
```

When running the task, It seems to execute it but why can't I see any output from echo (ie "hello") ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Arguments aren't supposed to be posted in `command`, so you're task should look like this:

```
{
  "command": "cmd",
  "args": ["/c", "c:\\test\\test.bat]
}
```

However, since Microsoft added auto-detection, the following should work as well:

```
{
  "type": "shell",
  "command": ""c:\\test\\test.bat"
}
```

See the [custom task documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks) for details.

Comment: ok thanks but my question was rather why I don't see "Hello" in Terminal or I am mistaken and your answer is directed at this ;)

Comment: I suspect that the ill-formed task might be the reason. Did you try yet?

Comment: I tried both of your code and got same result. must be something with my vscode maybe.

Comment: I deleted all my user settings and it worked so something in it prevented from working.